# Finding Array Size By Using end & begin in C++

Tags: c++, iterator

I have this piece of code that I need to find that array size by using `end` & `begin`

```
int nums[] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 20, 50};


cout << end(nums) - begin(nums) << "\n";
```

I just can't understand how both working together to get me the size of array?

I tried watching some YouTube videos and people keep saying "`end` is pointing to an imaginary number or imaginary position that follows the last number in the array."

Comment: Looks like you have the answer and you need to understand how the answer is obtained. Did you try printing begin and end individually and running a couple of times?

Comment: `std::array nums{10,20,30,40,50}; std::cout << nums.size() << "\n";`

Comment: A more general version of this uses [`std::distance()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) rather than subtraction.

Comment: `std::cout << std::size(nums);` is the best way.

Comment: It's not working with me..i tried to include array header file, vector..but i got nothing

Answer (score 4):

`std::begin()` with an array argument returns a *pointer* to the first element:

```
+----+----+----+----+----+
| 10 | 20 | 30 | 40 | 50 |
+----+----+----+----+----+
```

`std::end()` similarly returns a pointer just beyond the last element:

```
+----+----+----+----+----+
| 10 | 20 | 30 | 40 | 50 |
+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Together, these make a *half-open range* (begin is inclusive, and end is exclusive).

Because the iterators to a plain array are simple pointers, they can be subtracted to yield the size of the array (or we could simply use [`std::size()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size), of course).

In C, we would use `sizeof nums / sizeof *nums`, and that's still valid in C++, but less general than the standard library functions, which will work with all kinds of collection.

Comment: thanks..its just "std::size" isn't working with me, keep saying that "request for member ‘size’ in ‘nums’, which is of non-class "

Comment: Are you including the right header, and compiling as C++17 or later?

Comment: Oh, that error suggests you're writing `nums.size()`, rather than `std::size(nums)`.  The example in [`std::size()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) reference shows it quite well, with `assert(std::size(a) == 3);`.

Comment: Ah yes sorry about it, "Writing code on the phone is terrible XD" now it's saying "size’ is not a member of ‘std’; did you mean ‘size_t" when i tried to use size_t..gives me a very very big number..i guess my code is missing something, header file or something

Comment: "Not a member of `std`" as error suggests you're either not including any of the headers that define it, or you're compiling as C++14 or earlier, which didn't have `std::size()`.  [`std::size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) is a different beast - it's the arithmetic type that's returned by `std::size()`.

Comment: Okay, i'll try to solve it depending on my own